# Unable to config csp prop if Content Security Policy (CSP) is enabled in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have enabled the CSP in my project. I have created dashboard using antd but antd used the inline css so It is blocked by CSP. I am trying to pass nonce using config provider as mentioned in document https://ant.design/components/config-provider#Content-Security-Policy but It is not working.

```
 <ConfigProvider csp={{ nonce: 'YourNonceCode' }}>
      <Button>My Button</Button>
    </ConfigProvider>
```